# ActionListerner calls wrong id

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Suppose to have a data, where there are ten rows. In every rows there are a button "X" that it is used to delete row. My problem is that when I click on the "x" button delete always  the last row and not the row where I'm clicking.
the datable code is this:

```
<h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable id="studentsTable" var="student"
                lazy="true" value="#{studentBean.listStudents}"
                selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{studentBean.selectedStudent}" rows="10"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="2,5,10,15" rowKey="#{student.idStudent}">
```

....

This is the code button:

```
                    <p:confirm header="Confirm"
                        message="Delete student?"
                        icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                        <h:form>
                            <p:commandButton value="Yes"  process="@this"  styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
                                icon="pi pi-check" immediate="true"
                                actionListener="#{studentBean.deleteStudent(student)}" >

                            </p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                                icon="pi pi-times" />
                        </h:form>
                    </p:confirmDialog>

            </p:column>
```

the bean is :

```
public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
        this.studentDAO.delete(student.getIdStudent());

    }
```

I don't know why, when the method `deleteStudent` is called delete the last row  because it receives a wrong id. Anyone can help me?

Comment: [mcve], [ask] and version info, otherwise it would but guessing or suggeting and that is not where I'd like to spend my time. Cheers

Comment: try removing the additional form in your <p:confirmDialog> section

Comment: @Raphael_S I try and it doesn't work

Comment: I think that your code has a nested form. You start a `form` before `datatable` and you have another form in `confirmDialog` which is inside `datatable`. Try to remove `confirmDialog` dialog and check if it is working

Comment: @tsotzolas I found the error thanks to you!